# Trash folder is not emptying because of the P ͎̮͉͍ͨ̈́̾̈́A ͎̮͉͍ͨ̈́̾̈́I ͎̮͉͍ͨ̈́̾̈́N ͎̮͉͍ͨ̈́̾̈́.jpg file

Tags: macos, security, file, virus

When I `cd ~/.Trash` in the terminal, it shows that there is a folder `Downloads`, and inside the `Downloads` folder, another folder `Reactions`, and inside `Reactions`, there is a file called

[image: virus]

Shutting down or restarting the computer does not work to empty the trash. Also, I should say that the file is hidden and is not showing when I open the Trash folder. Is it a virus? If yes, how do I get rid of it?

[image: virus 2]

---

In terminal, using:  `cd ~/.Trash/Downloads/Reactions` and then `ls -al`, shows the jpg file.

(shown in the screenshot of the file because I could not copy and paste the text here in this question)

[image: virus 3]

`drwxrwxrwx  3 username  staff  102 Jan 19 14:36 .`

`drwxr-xr-x  3 username  staff  102 Jan 19 16:09 ..`

**Update 1**

I moved the `Reactions` out of the `Downloads` and emptied the trash. Now there is only `Reactions` left with the `.jpg` inside.

[image: virus 4]

By running `ls -aBeil ~/.Trash/Reactions` in terminal, following is the result:

[image: virus 5]

`36328284 drwxrwxrwx  3 username  staff  102 Jan 19 14:36 .`

`68013143 drwx------  3 username  staff  102 Jan 20 14:55 ..`

**Update 2**

From `cd ~/.Trash/Reactions` > `rm 'P` > enter <kbd>space</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>return</kbd>

Result is as follows:

[image: virus 6]

**Update 3**

Below is the result from `unset LANG ; ls -aBeil ~/.Trash/Reactions`:

[image: virus 7]

**Update 4**

Below is the result from utility disk verification:

[image: virus 8]

[image: virus 9]

**Update 5**

I just repaired the disk through `Disk Utility` using <kbd>command</kbd> + R access after system restart. Then, `.jpg` file is not hidden anymore and can be emptied on trash. Below you can see the screenshots.

[image: virus 10]

[image: virus 11]

Thank you all for your comments and answers. Special thanks to daniel Azuelos, patrix and klanomath.

Comment: Open Disk Utility and run "Check volume" on your main drive. It you get errors requiring a repair, boot into Recovery Mode, run Disk Util from there and use "Repair volume"

Comment: @patrix, pls take a look at update 4

Comment: "Illegal name", I actually like that. Please proceed as explained in the dialog box in the lower window, and then (once you have Disk Utility running in Recovery Mode) select "Repair Disk" (instead of verify). Afterwards reboot as usual and try emptying the trash again.

Comment: @patrix, thank you patrix, it worked. pls take a look at update 5.

Answer (score 9):

This answer may not really answer the question but provide some information what might had happened.

I've downloaded the torrent with 4Chan pictures containing the Pain.jpg and two other pics with hebrew chars.
Here is the diabolic culprit ;-)

[image: pain]

`ls -aBeil` shows:

```
mymac:Reactions user$ ls -aBeil  
ls: P ͎̮͉͍ͨ̈́̾̈́A ͎̮͉͍ͨ̈́̾̈́I ͎̮͉͍ͨ̈́̾̈́N ͎̮͉͍ͨ̈́̾̈́.jpg: No such file or directory         
total 528  
581705 drwxrwxrwx  6 user  staff     204 Jan 21 12:08 .  
401304 drwx------+ 6 user  staff     204 Jan 21 11:57 ..  
 0: group:everyone deny delete  
582449 -rw-r--r--@ 1 user  staff    6148 Jan 21 12:08 .DS_Store  
582261 -rw-r--r--  1 user  staff    4792 Jan 21 12:05 ה̌͐͊͒̾͆יͩ́א ͭ̆צ̿̒̃͛ו͋פͯ͆̉ה͑͑ͧ̇ͪ͆.jpg  
582094 -rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  253804 Jan 21 12:06 ה̌͐͊͒̾͆יͩ́א ͭ̆צ̿̒̃͛ו͋פͯ͆̉ה͑͑ͧ̇ͪ͆.xcf
```

`lsof -- . *` shows:

```
mymac:Reactions user$ lsof -- . *  
lsof: status error on P ͎̮͉͍ͨ̈́̾̈́A ͎̮͉͍ͨ̈́̾̈́I ͎̮͉͍ͨ̈́̾̈́N ͎̮͉͍ͨ̈́̾̈́.jpg: No such file or directory    
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME  
bash    1290 user  cwd    DIR    1,2      204 581705 .  
lsof    1345 user  cwd    DIR    1,2      204 581705 .  
lsof    1346 user  cwd    DIR    1,2      204 581705 .
```

All files were visible in the Finder except .DS_Store of course. Pain.jpg had a default icon and couldn't be opened. After moving Pain.jpg to the Downloads folder (at ~12:13 - check log below), waiting a few seconds and moving it back into the Reactions folder the preview icon appeared and the file could be opened.

[image: pain]

`ls -aBeil` now shows:

```
mymac:Reactions user$ ls -aBeil  
total 616  
581705 drwxrwxrwx  6 user  staff     204 Jan 21 12:14 .  
401304 drwx------+ 6 user  staff     204 Jan 21 12:14 ..  
 0: group:everyone deny delete  
582449 -rw-r--r--@ 1 user  staff    6148 Jan 21 12:14 .DS_Store  
581871 -rw-r--r--  1 user  staff   44041 Jan 21 12:01 P ͎̮͉͍ͨ̈́̾̈́A ͎̮͉͍ͨ̈́̾̈́I ͎̮͉͍ͨ̈́̾̈́N ͎̮͉͍ͨ̈́̾̈́.jpg  
582261 -rw-r--r--  1 user  staff    4792 Jan 21 12:05 ה̌͐͊͒̾͆יͩ́א ͭ̆צ̿̒̃͛ו͋פͯ͆̉ה͑͑ͧ̇ͪ͆.jpg  
582094 -rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  253804 Jan 21 12:06 ה̌͐͊͒̾͆יͩ́א ͭ̆צ̿̒̃͛ו͋פͯ͆̉ה͑͑ͧ̇ͪ͆.xcf
```

`lsof -- . *` shows:

```
mymac:Reactions user$ lsof -- . *  
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME  
bash    1290 user  cwd    DIR    1,2      204 581705 .  
lsof    1390 user  cwd    DIR    1,2      204 581705 .  
lsof    1391 user  cwd    DIR    1,2      204 581705 .
```

The corresponding log entries (sorry for the irritating hebrew chars cluttering the entries - at least editing and viewing them in Google Chrome - it's really difficult to format it at all):

```
21/01/15 12:07:10,734 QuickLookUIHelper[1231]: CoreAnimation: failed to create OpenGL context  
21/01/15 12:07:32,702 sandboxd[346]: ([1180]) mdworker(1180) deny file-read-xattr /Users/user/Desktop/Reactions ()  
21/01/15 12:08:03,862 QuickLookUIHelper[1248]: CoreAnimation: failed to create OpenGL context  
21/01/15 12:13:41,303 Finder[325]: sandbox extension creation failed: file system representation creation error for path: [/Users/user/Downloads/Reactions/P ͎̮͉͍ͨ̈́̾̈́A ͎̮͉͍ͨ̈́̾̈́I ͎̮͉͍ͨ̈́̾̈́N ͎̮͉͍ͨ̈́̾̈́.jpg]  
21/01/15 12:13:41,303 Finder[325]: __CFPasteboardCreateSandboxExtensionDataFromCFData : failed to obtain sandbox extension data for url [file:///.file/id=6571367.581871]  
21/01/15 12:13:41,304 Finder[325]: Failed to obtain a valid sandbox extension for item: [789514] of flavor: [public.file-url] from the pasteboard.  Because the sandbox extension failed to be generated..  
21/01/15 12:13:41,304 Finder[325]: Failed to get a sandbox extensions for itemIdentifier (789514).  The data for the sandbox extension was still proxy data  
21/01/15 12:13:47,518 Finder[325]: sandbox extension creation failed: file system representation creation error for path: [/Users/user/Downloads/Reactions/P ͎̮͉͍ͨ̈́̾̈́A ͎̮͉͍ͨ̈́̾̈́I ͎̮͉͍ͨ̈́̾̈́N ͎̮͉͍ͨ̈́̾̈́.jpg]  
21/01/15 12:13:47,518 Finder[325]: __CFPasteboardCreateSandboxExtensionDataFromCFData : failed to obtain sandbox extension data for url [file:///Users/user/Downloads/Reactions/P%20%CD%8E%CC%AE%CD%89%CD%8D%CD%A8%CC%88%CC%81%CC%BE%CC%88%CC%81A%20%CD%8E%CC%AE%CD%89%CD%8D%CD%A8%CC%88%CC%81%CC%BE%CC%88%CC%81I%20%CD%8E%CC%AE%CD%89%CD%8D%CD%A8%CC%88%CC%81%CC%BE%CC%88%CC%81N%20%CD%8E%CC%AE%CD%89%CD%8D%CD%A8%CC%88%CC%81%CC%BE%CC%88%CC%81.jpg]
```

Moving the whole Reactions folder to the trash and deleting it with the pics is no problem.
The same applies for copying the folder or moving it around.
The Pain.jpg - though really a PITA regarding proper display - doesn't seem to be a virus.

The problems in Finder and sandbox probably occur because of the strange naming of the file: mixed roman and hebrew chars. Hebrew only file names are notated right to left (see second picture). Additionally some filesystem damage may had happened.

My advices are:

- like others already mentioned: try to repair your main volume with 'Disk Utility' after rebooting to Recovery Mode
- move the file to another folder, wait some time and move it back to its origin until you see the preview image. Check your logs for the sandbox messages (see above).
- try to execute `find . -inum <inode> -exec rm {} \;` after successfully using `ls -aBeil` to get the inode of 'Pain.jpg'. In my case that would have been: `find . -inum 581871 -exec rm {} \;`
- reboot to Recovery Mode and try to execute the last command (`find . -inum <inode> -exec rm {} \;`) after repairing the filesystem.
- try to execute rm 'P\ ͎̮͉͍ͨ̈́̾̈́A\ ͎̮͉͍ͨ̈́̾̈́I\ ͎̮͉͍ͨ̈́̾̈́N\ ͎̮͉͍ͨ̈́̾̈́.jpg'

Comment: @danielAzuelos hmmm Bitsnoop is just a torrent site like piratebay or similar. I downloaded about 1400 pics via magnet link with µtorrent. i skipped most of them retaining only those with special chars. there was no *.dmg to download.

Comment: @klanomath, thanks for your informative answer ...

Comment: @danielAzuelos, I also had a collections of photos from torrents and this image perhaps was one of them ... I remember I noticed that there was an `exe` file inside the folder containing the `pain.jpg` image and unfortunately it was late because perhaps it was already executed when the folder opened.. I was able to remove the original folder containing the images with such names the day before yesterday with no problem ..

Comment: `find . -inum 581871 -exec rm {} \;` note: 581871 is the inode please check the first column of `ls -aBeil` result

Comment: In case it's of interest, here are the unicode values of the string of combining diacritics used after each latin character in the name of that file:  P 034e;032e;0349;034d;0368;0308;0301;033e;0308;0301;

Comment: @nelson i had no problem to delete the folder or the containing files - before and after moving it. Your command is useful but it seems like the OP can't execute `ls -aBeil` and get the proper inode number for the file.

Comment: @klanomath: I forget a key point. If your `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`, then any char is printable and the `-B` isn't of much help. To use it efficiently one should enter `unset LANG ; ls -aBeil`.

Comment: @danielAzuelos What a question and what a problem. I would like to swear here extensively now in written form. you are right `rm P....jpg` doesn't work and neither `rm 'P%20....jpg'` because the file name is too long.

Comment: @danielAzuelos, it was not `.exe`, as far as I remember, it was like `Unix Executable File` and disappeared once I tried to check the `Name` and `Kind` on it..

Comment: @Sami Did you try to check your volume with Disk Utility? And does `ls -aBeil` give an inode number for P/*a/*i/*n.jpg?

Comment: The FS of Sami is clearly damaged. But there is something wrong around this file name. @klanomath, could you run your 1st `ls` with the corrective `unset LANG` immediatly after the download of the suspicious file or disk image. A running `opensnoop` would be interesting.

Comment: @danielAzuelos Sure give me some minutes

Comment: @danielAzuelos here is [opensnoop](http://www62.zippyshare.com/v/wBfMZFo0/file.html) and [unset LANG ; ls -aBeil](http://pastebin.com/WfbRiZAT)

Comment: @danielAzuelos additionally [fseventer-pic](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WdV3F.jpg) which is much easier to examine than opensnoop

Comment: @klanomath: I was able to read the files dropped on imgur.com, pastebin.com, but not the one on zippyshare.com (opensnoop log). Does the error message "No such file or directory" disappear at the end of the download?
Is your FS corrupted after the end of the download (Illegal name)?

Comment: @danielAzuelos You can't download directly from zippyshare. You have to open the page and hit the big orange 'Download Now' button in the upper right corner. Probably your NoScript-Extension prevents you from downloading it. It should work - i just d/led it again. Or use a download manager like JDownloader...

Comment: I'm really sorry but this server is unusable. After opening me more than 10 new windows  of commercial advertising (most of them with about 10 hidden trackers) and another one to install a software, I threw in the towel :(.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20481/discussion-between-klanomath-and-daniel-azuelos).

Answer (score 4):

In normal use, the `rm` command is for removing *files*, and the `rmdir` command is for removing *folders*. `rm` will refuse to remove a folder, and `rmdir` will refuse to remove a file. And even then, `rmdir` won't remove a folder that contains anything beyond the artificial links to `.` and `..`.

Both of these limitations can be overcome by providing the `-r` switch (short for `recursive`) to `rm` as in `rm -r list_of_files_or_folders`. If asked to remove a folder, it will first remove everything inside, and then invoke `rmdir` internally to get rid of the folder. Subfolders are removed the same way, to any depth.

`rm` will complain if asked to remove something that can't be removed. However, adding the `-f` switch (short for `force`) tells it to make a best effort to overcome any obstacles that may come up. If it can't delete something either because it's locked or because its permissions say it can't be deleted, *and* you own the file, then as file owner you could unlock the file and/or change its permissions. With `-f`, the `rm` command will do these things silently without pestering you about it.

Short version:

```
cd ~/.Trash
rm -rf Downloads
```

Comment: I got the same errors `rm: Downloads/Reactions: Directory not empty` and `rm: Downloads: Directory not empty`

Answer (score 4):

First, `cd` into the Reactions folder:

```
cd ~/.Trash/Reactions
```

Then, type `rm`, a <kbd>space</kbd>, then the <kbd>tab</kbd> key.

This **should** autocomplete the first file in the directory.

**If it does**, you should be able to press <kbd>return</kbd> to delete the offending file.

Comment: The autocomplete works but I get the `No such file or directory` message

Answer (score 4):

Right click on the trash can, while holding down the Command key. An option 'Secure Empty Trash' will appear. Select this. Hopefully it will empty the trash folder for you.

Comment: It says `The operation can’t be completed because the item “Reactions” is in use.`

Comment: Run `cd ~/.Trash/Downloads/Reactions ; lsof -- . *`

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like it could be an illegal file name.

- Boot into single user mode, try running fsck -f
- Boot into Recovery Mode, run Disk Utility from there and select "Repair Disk"

Answer (score 3):

Boot the system into Single User mode by powering off and holding Command+S.  Then when you see `bash3.2#` type in `/sbin/mount -uw /` to mount the filesystem as readwrite.

Then,

1. `cd /Users/<your username>/` to move to your home directory
2. `rm -rf .Trash` to force delete the trash directory
3. `mkdir .Trash` to recreate the trash directory
4. `chmod 700 .Trash` to set the proper permissions on the folder
5. `chown <your username> .Trash` to set your user as the folders owner
6. `reboot` to reboot and exit single user mode

Comment: I got the same errors `rm: .Trash/Downloads: Directory not empty` and `rm: .Trash: Directory not empty`

Comment: This answer is risky. The `.Trash` doesn't get the default ACL it has by default. Moreover on a corrupted FS it won't work. It's easier to say this now that we know the FS is damaged :).

Answer (score 3):

Try and move the folder `Downloads` out of the trash

Then run in terminal:

`defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool yes;osascript -e "tell application \"finder\" to quit";osascript -e "tell application \"finder\" to activate"`

This will allow you to see hidden files in the **Finder** GUI file system.

If you can see the ...jeg   file in the downloads or Reactions folders. Can you rename it. If so do so. and the try and delete it.

run in terminal:

`defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool no;osascript -e "tell application \"finder\" to quit";osascript -e "tell application \"finder\" to activate"`

To reset the system to hidden.

---

You can run just the `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool yes`

in terminal.app  and the manually Relaunch the finder. Using it's dock icon.

Hold down the <kbd>alt</kbd> key and then click the finders dock icon.

[image]

Comment: I moved the `Downloads` into desktop and followed your method. When I run the first command in terminal, everything hides on my desktop, then running your second command, desktop files appears again.

Comment: I also moved `Reactions` folder out of `Downloads`, and again deleted the files and emptied trash. Now, only `Reactions` with the hidden file inside left in the trash.

Comment: My system is always with `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE;killall Finder`, but the file inside `Reactions` is not showing up

Comment: But if you ls -a on the folder you see it?

Comment: Yes I can see that. It doesnt rename the file and says `mv: rename ... to hi.jpg: No such file or directory`. Note that I can not copy paste the filename here.

Comment: @Sami  try and change the Reaction folder's name

Answer (score 2):

Try following the steps outlined in Apple's support document on this subject.Many of the items in the document are included in the suggestions here, but they offer some items to try for severe cases such as yours. Rather than repeat them all here, its best to simply refer to this well written document on the subject.

http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201583

If all else fails, you might try creating a small boot thumbdrive using PuppyLinux or other such distro, then boot from that thumnbdrive. Mount the Mac harddrive, then navigate to the folder and delete the file.

Comment: Alternative to Linux booting: target disk mode and mount as a dumb drive on another Mac?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps it is not possible because you file is in an folder that is located in the download folder? Place back the files on your desktop, open the folder 'downloads' and delete what's in that folder. Try to empty your trash can now.